# Unable to read CSV file for huge number of data in spring boot by using postman as client

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

From spring boot application while reading 1 million data from CVS file getting errors show below.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded


2020-03-29 23:05:22.886 ERROR 10772 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Below is java Code

```
   @Transactional
private void readFileFromFile(FileUploadDetails fileUploadDetail) throws IOException {

    String filePath = fileUploadDetail.getFilePath();
    try {
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filePath);
         CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader) 
                 .withSkipLines(1) 
                 .build(); 
        List<FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog> fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog = new ArrayList<>();

        // we are going to read data line by line

          List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
            int count=0;
            for (String[] cell : allData) {
                FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog fileAESurveyLogVo = new FileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog();
                fileAESurveyLogVo.setYear(cell[0].toString());
                ...............................................
                fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog.add(fileAESurveyLogVo);
                //fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.save(fileAESurveyLogVo);
                //fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.
                System.out.println(count);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("waseem"+fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog.size());

            fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyRepository.save(fileAnnualEnterpriseSurveyLog);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

So could you please suggest me this a good approach to read large amount of data

Comment: Have you tried to read it as a stream or line-by-line rather than as a whole file?

Comment: [Read large CSV in java ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918668/unable-to-read-csv-file-for-huge-number-of-data-in-spring-boot-by-using-postman?noredirect=1#comment107782713_60918668). This not right solution to my post. I try that but it is struck at  nextLine = reader.readNext()  line. At this line taking too much time and it is not coming out side to loop

Comment: You load everything into memory, and then afterwards write it out. Instead try to save per line (or per `n` lines (eg per 100 lines)).